# convert a statement into a prepared statement java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

```
static int R;

stmt = conn.createStatement();

String query = "SELECT Points.Name, Points.x, Points.y FROM Points + "WHERE Points.x>=" + (x-R) + " AND Points.x<="+ (x + R) + " AND Points.y>=" + (y - R) + " AND Points.y<="+ (y + R) + " AND Points.Name='" + name + "'";

rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
```

Could someone help me convert the above query into another for a prepared statement?

Comment: You're looking for the documentation.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Well what have you tried so far? The code you've given isn't even valid Java. Have you read any tutorials?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#prepareStatement(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ps = con.prepareStatement("select concat(first_name,' ',last_name) as full_name from employee where salary between ? and ?");
int i=1;
ps.setInt(i++, 30000);
ps.setInt(i++, 40000);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Replace parameters with "?" and add then afterward one by one. Then execute.

Answer (score 2):

```
static int R;

String query = "SELECT Points.Name, Points.x, Points.y FROM Points WHERE Points.x>= ? AND Points.x<= ? AND Points.y>= ? AND Points.y<= ? AND Points.Name= ?";

PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);

stmt.setString(1, x-R);
stmt.setString(2, x+R);
/* etc.. etc..  */
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();

while(rs.next()) {

    /* read your RS and do stuff */

}
```

Note, that to take proper advantage of `PReparedStatement` it's common to setup/initialize all of your `PreparedStatement`s from your class' constructor. This way, as soon as you construct your object, your statements have already been sent to the database, the database has compiled your statements and is ready to accept your paramatized inputs (`setString(x, x);`).

Comment: `stmt.setInt(1, x - R)` - or so - more likely.

Comment: @JoopEggen right, this was a quick example. Note, that it doesn't matter, you can use `setString()` on most things, it just causes the database to do extra work in converting the datatype on it's end.